# Ignore case and compare in C#

Tags: c#, .net, string-comparison

How to convert the string to uppercase before performing a compare, or is it possible to compare the string by ignoring the case

```
 if (Convert.ToString(txt_SecAns.Text.Trim()).ToUpper() == 
     Convert.ToString(hidden_secans.Value).ToUpper())
```

Comment: Your code is locale dependent. Do you really want that?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

use this:

```
var result = String.Compare("AA", "aa", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

[String.Compare Method (String, String, Boolean)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkcaxw5y.aspx)

Answer (score 20):

Case-insensitive string comparison is done like this in C#:

```
string.Equals("stringa", "stringb", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
```

**Watch out!** this code is culture dependant; there are several other options available, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison.aspx.

Comment: Using the Turkish culture this code can return false for `STRINGA` and `stringa`. It's very well possible that the OP wants that, but it's important to be aware that culture influences case insensitive comparisons

Comment: If you want it to be culture invariant than use this `string.Equals("stringa", "stringb", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)`

Comment: What's the difference between this and `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase`?

Answer (score 5):

Well, you can use `String.Equals(String,StringComparison)` method. Just pass it `StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` or `StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase` depending on your objectives...

Answer (score 4):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkcaxw5y.aspx):

String.Compare Method (String, String, Boolean):

```
public static int Compare(
    string strA,
    string strB,
    bool ignoreCase
)
```

so in your case:

```
if( String.Compare(txt_SecAns.Text.Trim(), hidden_secans.Value, true) == 0)
```

Answer (score 3):

Just like this:

```
if (string.Compare(txt_SecAns.Text.Trim(), hidden_secans.Value.ToString(), true) == 0)
{
    // DoSomething
}
```

The third parameter `true` tells string.Compare to ignore case.

Answer (score 3):

```
txt_SecAns.Trim().Compare(hidden_secans.Trim(), StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
```

Answer (score 3):

string.Compare(string1, string2, true) == 0 will compare if the two strings are equal ignoring case

Answer (score 3):

Use `StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase`:

```
if (txt_SecAns.Text.Trim().Equals(hidden_secans.Value.ToString(), StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
String.Compare(str1, str2, true);
```

Comment: I'd prefer a method that explicitly specifies the culture. It's not obvious that this uses the current culture.

Comment: Yes, this version uses the current culture according to MSDN. There is an overload with a fourth parameter that lets you specify the culture explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

I would personaly compare with a proper culture like everyone here, but something hasn't been suggested :

```
public bool CompareStrings(string stringA, string StringB)
{
    return stringA.ToLower() == stringB.ToLower();
}
```

Comment: I think the results from this can still differ from using a case insensitive comparer with the same culture.

Comment: It can, but I think it would address the issue you pointed out with the Turkish culture. Would it?

Comment: `"I".ToLower()!="i".ToLower()` On a Turkish system.

Comment: Oh, wow. I didn't expect that! Well, I think I'll stick with my non-Turkish mindset! ;-)